# Store user and global data for use later

Tags: iphone, global-variables, storage

**Question:** How and where should I store my users information and other global data that comes from the database when the user logs in?

Background: When my user logs into the application I want to do another database call (beyond the authentication process) that grabs a lot of the general global information out of the database and store it somewhere that my application can get it later during different parts of the application.

I am a new iPhone developer so I am always open to other recommendations and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in `"AppDelegate.h"` like declare a array or dict. there and when you got 
data assign him.

The Another way is store all your data in `NSUserDefault`

```
//Save
NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefault setValue:YourData forKey:@"LoginData"];
[userDefault synchronize];
```

YourData should be in array or dictnory.

```
//Get
Array/dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"LoginData"];
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setValue:@"Value" forKey:@"Key"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Then Use it,

```
NSString *st = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"Key"];
```

Hopefully this will help you